# How to make intercommunication between RPi and webpage

Tags: jquery, ajax, web, websocket, raspberry-pi

I am a new hand in the RPi,Python and webpage technology.
I plan to use a RPi as a web server,the client can connect it via a browser.
On the webpage,the client can press a button to let the RPi take a picture(stored in the RPi SD card) and the RPi shows the real-time GPS position on the webpage 
I think it is a intercommunication problem,someone said that I could use AJAX or Websocket,is there any template or sample?THX.
BTW,if you have any suggestion,pls tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed a LAMP server on my RPi, and it works fine.
Then you just add your web files in the /var/www folder.

You can use php to let the user upload files, like pictures.
The php code could look something like this.

```
<?php
    if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 0) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $ok = false;
    switch ($mime) {
       case 'image/jpeg':
            $ok = true;
            break;
       default:
           echo "";
    }
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/pic{$id}.jpeg"
    }
?>
```

To show GPS coordinates on your webpage you can use this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[w3schools GPS coordinates](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation)